# Add Upload type to GraphQL

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, graphql, apollo

I am trying to create a custom resolver to upload an user's avatar image for an Express + Apollo Server + Mongoose project which is using [composeWithMongoose](https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-mongoose).

User resolvers are being created with `SchemaComposer`, which generates them from the Mongoose schema like:

#### User Model

```js
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import timestamps from 'mongoose-timestamp';
import bcrypt from 'mongoose-bcrypt';
import { composeWithMongoose } from 'graphql-compose-mongoose';

export const UserSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            trim: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        phone: {
            type: Number,
            trim: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            bcrypt: true,
        },
        type: {
            type: String,
        },
        image: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            lowercase: true,
        },
    },
    {
        collection: 'users',
    }
);

UserSchema.plugin(timestamps);
UserSchema.plugin(bcrypt);

UserSchema.index({ createdAt: 1, updatedAt: 1 });

export const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
export const UserTC = composeWithMongoose(User);
```

#### User Schema

```js
import { User, UserTC } from '../models/user';

const UserQuery = {
    userById: UserTC.getResolver('findById'),
    userByIds: UserTC.getResolver('findByIds'),
    userOne: UserTC.getResolver('findOne'),
    userMany: UserTC.getResolver('findMany'),
    userCount: UserTC.getResolver('count'),
    userConnection: UserTC.getResolver('connection'),
    userPagination: UserTC.getResolver('pagination'),
};

const UserMutation = {
    userCreateOne: UserTC.getResolver('createOne'),
    userCreateMany: UserTC.getResolver('createMany'),
    userUpdateById: UserTC.getResolver('updateById'),
    userUpdateOne: UserTC.getResolver('updateOne'),
    userUpdateMany: UserTC.getResolver('updateMany'),
    userRemoveById: UserTC.getResolver('removeById'),
    userRemoveOne: UserTC.getResolver('removeOne'),
    userRemoveMany: UserTC.getResolver('removeMany'),
};

export { UserQuery, UserMutation };
```

According to [graphql-compose-mongoose documentation](https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-mongoose#how-can-i-pushpop-or-addremove-values-to-arrays) and what I understood I have to add the resolver to the `ObjectTypeComposer` (`UserTC`) using the method `addResolver()` like:

#### User Schema

```js
import { User, UserTC } from '../models/user';
import { GraphQLUpload } from 'graphql-upload';

UserTC.addResolver({
    name: 'uploadImage',
    type: 'String',
    args: { userId: 'MongoID!', image: 'Upload!' },
    resolve: async ({ source, args, context, info }) => {
        const user = await User.findById({ _id: args.userId }).exec();
        console.log(user);
    }
});

const UserQuery = {
    ...
};

const UserMutation = {
    ...
    uploadImage: UserTC.getResolver('uploadImage'),
};

export { UserQuery, UserMutation };
```

This was working until I changed the `image` argument type from `String` to `Upload`. Where, according to [Apollo documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/file-uploads/) is enabled by default.

I get this error in console: `Error: Type with name "Upload" does not exists`.

But I am not sure how to add to my own type definitions using `composeWithMongoose()` in this case.

I am interested to hear other methods - maybe using an entirely different approach is completely valid.

### Edit 1: In response to @Daniel Rearden

I am still getting `Upload` type does not exists:

> ```
>   throw new Error(`Type with name ${(0, _misc.inspect)(typeName)} does not exists`);
>
>  ^
> ```
>
> Error: Type with name "Upload" does not exists

1. I have installed: `express-graphql` and `apollo-upload-server`.
2. I added the middlewares to the server configuration:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { apolloUploadExpress } from 'apollo-upload-server'; 
import './utils/db';
import schema from './schema';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(
    bodyParser.json(),
    apolloUploadExpress()
);

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    cors: true,
    playground: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? true : false,
    introspection: true,
    tracing: true,
    path: '/',
});
...
```

3. I have provided the following code inside the Schema index:

```js
import { SchemaComposer } from 'graphql-compose';
import { GraphQLUpload } from 'apollo-upload-server';

import db from '../utils/db'; //eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

const schemaComposer = new SchemaComposer();

schemaComposer.add(GraphQLUpload);
...
```

And I am still getting the error: `Error: Type with name "Upload" does not exists`.

### Edit 2: Also, in response to @Daniel Rearden

Well, I just added the custom resolver to the `UserMutation` schema and it worked:

```js
const UserMutation = {
    userCreateOne: UserTC.getResolver('createOne'),
    userCreateMany: UserTC.getResolver('createMany'),
    userUpdateById: UserTC.getResolver('updateById'),
    userUpdateOne: UserTC.getResolver('updateOne'),
    userUpdateMany: UserTC.getResolver('updateMany'),
    userRemoveById: UserTC.getResolver('removeById'),
    userRemoveOne: UserTC.getResolver('removeOne'),
    userRemoveMany: UserTC.getResolver('removeMany'),
    uploadImage: {
        type: 'String',
        args: {
            userId: 'String!',
            image: 'Upload'
        },
        resolve: async (_, { userId, image }) => {
            const user = await User.findById({ _id: userId}).exec();
            console.log(user);
        },
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the docs state:

> Note: When using typeDefs, Apollo Server adds scalar Upload to your schema, so any existing declaration of scalar Upload in the type definitions should be removed. If you create your schema with makeExecutableSchema and pass it to ApolloServer constructor using the schema param, make sure to include scalar Upload.

If you're not utilizing the `typeDefs` and `resolvers` options and instead passing a `schema` directly to `ApolloServer`'s constructor, you have to add the scalar yourself. `graphql-compose`'s docs show [how to do this](https://graphql-compose.github.io/docs/guide/file-uploads.html) but it should be as simple as:

```
import { schemaComposer } from 'graphql-compose'
import { GraphQLUpload } from 'apollo-server'

schemaComposer.add(GraphQLUpload)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I have edited the question to respond you.

Comment: The only way I found till now is to add the custom resolver inside the `schemaComposer.Mutation.addFields()`, in the Schema index file. But there I need to access to the `Ùser` model.